# What is the preferred method of accessing metamodel data in JPA 2.0 Criteria API? Generating static classes, or using the API?

Tags: jpa-2.0, criteria-api

I have seen two different methods for accessing the entity metamodel information in JPA 2.0. The first is by using the static canonical metadata classes that have been generated with an annotation processor.   The second is by using the Root.getModel() API or the EntityManager.getMetaModel().entity() API.  I am currently using the first method (by generating them at design time), but I'm interested in what the pros and cons are between the two, and which is best practice.  Are there significant performance differences between the two?  Will I get compile-time type checking with the API method?  I hope this is one of those topics that will spark some debate so I can hear some good ideas.  Thank you!